# Specify column MaxLength on JSON column in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have two classes that represent tables in my database:

```sharp
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

I also have this `DbContext` class

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
        ...
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().OwnsOne(x => x.Child, y => y.ToJson());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
```

When I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add SomeContext_Initial
```

EF Core generates a migration something like this:

```
...
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Parent",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Child = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
        }
    }
...
}
```

I use SQL Server as my database. As far as I know, SQL Server automatically moves `Child` column to pages [in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#large-row-support) because `Child` column has column type `nvarchar(max)` even if the content of column is significantly smaller than 8060 bytes (`PropertyA` and `PropertyB` data length in sum is expected to be about 1000 in serialized form).

This is something I clearly don't want for performance reasons.

Even if I specify a length of `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`, the migration tool still generates `Child` column as datatype `nvarchar(max)`.

I've tried to specify column length using `.HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 1000)` (or using attribute `[MaxLength(1000)]` on `Child` property) and that had no effect.

I've also tried to specify column type `nvarchar(1000)` and that also had no effect

Is there any way to achieve column length different from `nvarchar(max)` except editing the migration file manually?

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? the OVERFLOW will only be used if nvarchar(max) are actually over 4k i think. I get that one wants to size up the fields correctly, but maybe it's a bit of overkill in this case

Comment: Just to say, I was intrigued by the question and tried a bunch of ideas including configuring a default `MaxLength` convention. Nothing worked. Googled it to death. Hopefully EF Core 8 will have a solution.

Answer (score -2):

try using this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
[Table("sqlTableName", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Child 
{
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think he specifically didn't want MAX datatypes

Comment: I have tested this and it doesn't work, even if you change the column TypeNames to `VARCHAR(1000)`. @kerim did you test this?